# Fatal error: Call to undefined function countdown() in C:\xampp\htdocs\webdev\div.php on line 53

Tags: php

I've been toying around with a Christmas countdown, but for some reason I'm getting an error. I know it has to be because I didn't close something, but I can't pinpoint what it is. What am I missing here?

```
<?php


$year = '2015';
$month= '12';
$day = '25';
$hour = '00';
$minute = '00';
$second = '00';
$date = array($hour,$minute,$second,$month,$day,$year);

date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');

//Defining class bt keyword class
class DateCountDown {

//Class member definition - Easy to remember class members
var $year = "";
var $month= "";
var $day = "";
var $hour = "";
var $minute = "";
var $second = "";
var $date = "";
var $dl = "";
var $hl = "";
var $ml = "";
var $sl = "";
var $return = "";

//Countdown to particular Function
function countdown(){
global $return;
global $countdown_date;
global $date;
list ($hour, $minute, $second, $month, $day, $year)= $date;
$countdown_date = mktime($hour, $minute, $second, $month, $day, $year);
$today = time();
$diff = $countdown_date - $today;
if ($diff < 0)$diff = 0;
$dl = floor($diff/60/60/24);
$hl = floor(($diff - $dl*60*60*24)/60/60);
$ml = floor(($diff - $dl*60*60*24 - $hl*60*60)/60);
$sl = floor(($diff - $dl*60*60*24 - $hl*60*60 - $ml*60));
// OUTPUT
$return = array($dl, $hl, $ml, $sl);
return ($return);
}
}
//Making New Object for the class CountDownDate
$date_obj = new DateCountDown($date);
//Function (Method) call by an object to function countdown
$date_obj - countdown();

//Making varialbes $dl => Days Left, $hl => Hours Left and so on from $return array
list($dl,$hl,$ml,$sl) = $return;

//Browser Output
echo "Today is: ".date("F j, Y, g:i:s A")."<br/><br/>";
echo "<h1 style='color: green; background-color: #000000; border: 2px solid red; width: 400px; padding: 20px; text-align: center;'>Christmas Countdown</h1> <br/><br/>".date("F j, Y, g:i:s A",$countdown_date)."<br/>";
echo "\n<br>";
echo "".$dl." days ".$hl." hours ".$ml." minutes ".$sl." seconds left till Christmas!"."\n<br>";

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$date_obj - countdown();
```

should be:

```
$date_obj->countdown();
```

Comment: Yup that was it! Thanks.

Comment: In 2 more minutes, it'll allow me to